# Phone number Validation regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, magento, preg-replace

I want to validate phone number field on Magento Checkout address field.

I have used below magento default validation but which seems to be not working

```
    "validate-phoneStrict": [
        function(value) {
            return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || /^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/.test(value);
        },
        $.mage.__('Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.')
    ],
    "validate-phoneLax": [
        function(value) {
            return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || /^((\d[\-. ]?)?((\(\d{3}\))|\d{3}))?[\-. ]?\d{3}[\-. ]?\d{4}$/.test(value);
        },
        $.mage.__('Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.')
    ],
```

I want only these two formats to be valid `(123) 456-7890` or `123-456-7890`

Unfortunately it also accepts `(123456-7890` or `(123-456-7890`

I only want strict `(123) 456-7890` or `123-456-7890` this format only.

Any suggestion for regexp ?

Comment: So two different regular expressions for `phoneStrict` and `phoneLax`? which one is for which?

Comment: I am using validate-phoneStrict now

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
^(?:(?:\(\d{3}\)\s|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4})$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/deRv2x/8)